# Can I track my stolen iPhone 5 if the SIM is removed and the thief tries to hook it up to iTunes to restore it?

Tags: iphone, itunes

Can I track my iPhone 5 if the thief removed the sim card but tries to use iTunes to factory reset it? Could I track it if does not have a network connection without the sim?

Comment: How do you know it was stolen, did you just loose it?, call your own number and see if they pick up.

Comment: I found a phone once, a smart phone, and could not figure out who is the owner. So I waited and waited for them to call so I can return it. The call newer came :(

Answer (score 1):

If you had it set up with Find My Device via iCloud, you can log into iCloud.com and find it, erase it, and even see the last place it had network access at.